# Differential equation for current driven RC circuit

Tags: current-source, differential

I need the differential equation for the following circuit for numerical integration purpose.
It is driven by a time dependent current source.

So the question is:

How can I know \$U(t+dt)\$ given \$i(t)\$ and \$U(t)\$?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffPqfK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Would shorting-out R2 help you find a solution yourself?

Comment: yes, R2 is actually not necessary in the question, as it adds only an offset proportional to the current on the total voltage.
I'll simplify the problem

Comment: @Any aka: I gues you mean "opening-out" the resistor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, I actually consider that the current is only charging the cap, and that in parallel the cap is being discharged by the resistor.

\$dv = \frac{1}{C}i(t)dt-\frac{1}{C}\frac{U(t)}{R}dt\$

\$dv =\frac{1}{C}(i(t)-\frac{U(t)}{R})dt\$

and now I can integrate it

\$ U(t+dt)=U(t) + dv\$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Picture taken from [this site](http://uhaweb.hartford.edu/ltownsend/Series_and_Parallel_Equations_from_a_DE_perspective.pdf).